# Why does Minitest seem to not always report what the 'Actual' results of the test are?

Tags: ruby, minitest

Why does MiniTest sometimes truly display what's 'Actual' and sometimes it will just show a nil/blank/quote.

Example - I know that the value of a.join has "Hi" displayed on 2 lines with a blank line.

```
class Question

  def stack
    "Hi\n" \
    "Hi\n"  
  end

  def overflow
    a = []
    a << stack + "\n"   # This + "\n" is in question
    a.join              # This is "hi"s
  end
end

a = Question.new
puts a.overflow
```

If I take out the `+ "\n"` the test will say the "Actual" is just a quote instead of what it actually is (which is "Hi" printed on 2 lines). If I replace 'a.join' with "Tadah!" then Minitest will then show "Tadah!" under the "Actual".

I have the following test:

```
def test_verses
  expected = "Hi\n" \
  "Hi\n\n"
  assert_equal expected, Question.new.overflow
end
```

I've seen this happen several times. I can never tell if I TRULY have a nil result, or if Minitest is just "lying" to me again for some reason.

Thx as always!

Comment: Can you show what result you are getting, and what you are expecting? This seems to work ok for me.

Comment: It works fine as displayed. But if I change `a << stack + "\n"` to `a << stack`, then I get this from the terminal running the test (notice how actual is just a quote/nil and not the "Hi"s) : 
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1,4 +1,3 @@
 "Hi
 Hi
-
 "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from Minitest is a [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) of the expected result and the actual (I think it actually calls the external `diff` command). There isn’t  separate ‘expected’ and ‘actual’ sections, it’s all mixed together in a format that shows the differences.

In this case, when you remove the `"\n", the failure looks something like this:

```
  1) Failure:
Foo#test_verses [foo.rb:22]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1,4 +1,3 @@
 "Hi
 Hi
-
 "
```

The `--- expected` and `+++ actual` indicate that in the diff (which is shown after the `@@...` line) lines that start with `-` were expected to appear but didn’t, and lines that start with `+` appeared in the result but shouldn’t have. In this example there is an empty line that starts with `-`. This means that a newline was expected to appear in the output, but didn’t. This corresponds to the `+ "\n"` that you removed, but the test was expecting. The quote on the line following the `-` line is the end quote for the entire diff, not the contents of the ‘expected’ section.

When you change the return value of the `overflow` method to `"Tadah!"`, the failure message looks like this:

```
  1) Failure:
Foo#test_verses [foo.rb:23]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1,4 +1 @@
-"Hi
-Hi
-
-"
+"Tadah!"
```

Looking at the lines starting with `-` you can see the entire expected message was missing, and the line starting with `+` shows there was an extra line containing `Tadah!`. This case is also different in that Minitest has displayed the output as two separate strings (note the two separate sets of quotes).

Comment: So minitest looks at an entire line and says, "If these two are the same, then don't bother displaying it." So, it remains 'quiet' until it hits the newline code and realizes things are different, and displays what it actually got? I'm still not sure why it wouldn't at least give me a `+` for the actual (like it does with "Tadah!" though vs just being completely blank.) When I see Minitest not give me a `+` for the Actual, should just immediately know it's a newline character issue?

Comment: @TonyDiNitto the lines starting with `-` or `+` are where the actual result differs from the expected result. Where the actual result is the same as the expected result the line isn’t marked. It’s only the parts that are missing or are extra that are highlighted.